# Flexbox align-items: center

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment, vertical-alignment

So basically my problem is that whenever I want to use align-items: center with an h1 and a nav-bar, it doesn't work. I mean, it centers both but not quite right. This is the part of the code I'm interested in:

```
<header class="main-header">

  <h1>The Code Magazine</h1>

  <nav>
    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Challenges</a>
    <a href="#">Flexbox</a>
    <a href="#">CSS Grid</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The css should work when I just select the container for both the h1 and the nav, and set it to flex like this:

`.main-header { display: flex; align-items: center; }`

but when I do that this is the result:
[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTEZA.png)

And this is how it's supossed to look:

[This is the result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raN6p.jpg)

Hope someone could help me out here, I'm quite new in CSS. Thanks.

Comment: What result you want, its not specified in the question? (like you want space between  heading and nav)

Comment: align-items center centers the items vertically and this is happening correctly with your given code (try giving the main header a background color to check). Are you trying to justify the content in some way - that means lay them out in the horizontal direction. There are several options for this.

Comment: Could you both please take a look at the second image I posted? That is how It should look like, but in mine, even though it's center somehow doesn't look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare between lower case and upper case, try this https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-cache-dds7id?file=/index.html:246-281

Comment: Omg that worked. Thank you so much! tbh I don't get why ussing upper case on the h1 solved this, but after so many tries I'll buy anything haha. Tx and good day.